# Why is strlen causing a segmentation fault in C?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, c-strings

(Warning) Yes this is a part of an assignment I am working on, but I am completely desperate at this point and NO I am not looking for you guys to solve it for me, but any hint would be much appreciated!(/Warning)

I am pretty much trying to make an interactive menu, the user is meant to input an expression (For example "5 3 +") and the program should detect that it's in postfix notation, unfortunately I have been getting segmentation fault errors and I suspect they have something to do with the use of the **strlen** function.

> EDIT: I was able to make it work, first the `char expression[25] = {NULL};` line
> becomes `char expression[25] = {'\0'};`
>
> And when calling the `determine_notation` function I removed the `[25]` from the array I am passing like so:
> `determine_notation(expression, expr_length);`
>
> Also the `input[length]` part I changed to `input[length-2]` since like mentioned in a previous comment, `input[length] == '\0'` and `input[length--] == '\n'`.
>
> All in all thanks for all the help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int determine_notation(char input[25], int length);

int main(void)
{
    char expression[25] = {NULL}; // Initializing character array to NULL
    int notation;
    int expr_length;

    printf("Please enter your expression to detect and convert it's notation: ");
    fgets( expression, 25, stdin );

    expr_length = strlen(expression[25]); // Determining size of array input until the NULL terminator
    notation = determine_notation( expression[25], expr_length ); 
    printf("%d\n", notation);
}

int determine_notation(char input[25], int length) // Determines notation
{

    if(isdigit(input[0]) == 0)
    {
        printf("This is a prefix expression\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else if(isdigit(input[length]) == 0)
    {
        printf("This is a postfix expression\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("This is an infix expression\n");
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: `input[length]` is `'\0'` (and: ``input[length-1]` is `'\n'` And: `expression[25];` indexes beyond the object's size)

Comment: strlen gets a string (pointer-to-first-character), not a character.

Comment: `char expression[25] = {NULL};` has no sence. replace by `{'\0'}` or `""`

Comment: Take your compiler's warnings serious. Its debugging help for free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably got a warning explaining that you are converting a `char` to a pointer in this call:

```
expr_length = strlen(expression[25]);
//                             ^^^^
```

This is the problem - your code is referencing a non-existent element past the end of the array (an undefined behavior) and tries to pass it to `strlen`.

Since `strlen` takes a pointer to the beginning of the string, the call needs to be

```
expr_length = strlen(expression); // Determining size of array input until the NULL terminator
```

Comment: I see, this has solved part of my problem. At least now it actually ENTERS the function. Thanks a ton!